# How to transform these operations into cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I've been asked to do the following assignment.

Transform the following operations to cylindrical coordinates; let $A = \frac{7}{2} xi + 2y^2 j + 7zk$ and $B = 2xi + \frac{2}{3} j-2zk$ a) Divergence of A, b) double Rotational of A, c) rotational of A B.

Here is my approach:

For cylindrical coordinates

$$ x = \rho \ cos \ \phi \quad y = \rho \ sin \ \phi \ z = z$$

a) If I choose not to use general coordinates and just evaluate $\nabla A$ and then replace x,y and z from cylindrical coordinates gives

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {\partial A_1}{\partial \rho} + \frac {\partial A_2}{\partial \phi} + \frac {\partial A_3}{\partial z}$$

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {7x}{2} + 2 y^2 + 7z $$

Since x, y and z has a corresponding value for cylindrical coordinates replacing it gives:

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {\partial}{\partial \rho} \frac {7\rho \ cos \ \phi}{2}  + \frac {\partial \ 2 \rho^2 sin^2 \ \phi}{\partial \phi} + \frac {\partial 7z}{\partial z}$$

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {7 cos \phi}{2} + 2 \rho^2 sin \ 2\phi + 7$$

Which I believe is the answer, however, If I do it by considering the general coordinates where:

$$ h_\rho = 1 \qquad h_\phi = \rho \qquad h_z = 1 $$

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {1}{h_\rho h_\phi h_z} [ \frac {\partial h_\phi h_z A_1 }{\partial \rho} + \frac {\partial h_z h_\rho A_2 }{\partial \phi} + \frac {\partial h_\rho h_\phi A_3 }{\partial z}]$$

Replacing h values and x,y and z in cylindrical coordinates

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {1}{\rho} [ \frac {\partial}{\partial \rho} \rho (\frac{7 \rho cos \ \phi}{2}) + \frac {\partial}{\partial \phi} (2 \rho^2 sin^2 \ \phi) + \frac {\partial}{\partial z} \rho(7z)]$$

$$\nabla \cdot A = \frac {1}{\rho} [ \frac {7 cos \phi}{2} (2 \rho) + 2\rho^2 (sin 2\phi) + 7\rho]$$

$$\nabla \cdot A = 7 \ cos \phi + 2\rho \ sin 2\phi + 7$$

As you can see I obtained two different result when doing $\nabla A$ when using general coordinates and just evaluating without using general coordinates. Which one is the correct answer? If you have any comments on my answer please let me know.

b) On this I don't know what it means double rotational, is it $\nabla^2 \times A$ ? or $\nabla \times (\nabla \times A)$

c) On this last one since I am confused on how to convert to cylindrical coordinates properly. If I try to do something like, let X be a vector and change it to cylindrical coordinates I know how to do it, but If I am asked to do something like evaluate:

$$ A \times B $$
or
$$ A \cdot B $$
or
$$ \nabla \cdot A $$

I do not understand how to do it (in exercise a I obtained two different answers). And last, what does it mean rotational of AB, is it $\nabla \times (A\cdot B)$ or is it $\nabla \times (A\times B)$.

Comment: The correct answer for $\nabla \cdot A$ is 

$\frac{\partial \ (7x/2)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \ (2y^2)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \ (7z)}{\partial z} = \frac{21}{2} + 4y = \frac{21}{2} + 4 \rho \sin \varphi$

Comment: But the question asks you to transform the operations to cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I'm learning vector calculus using the book Schaum's Outline of Vector Analysis, 2ed. With the answer you are giving me, does that mean I do not have to use the formula of divergent of a vector using general coordinates and just evaluate the divergent and then replace the x,y and z on whatever coordinates I'm asked to convert?

Comment: No I am just telling you what the final answer should be. You are supposed to first convert the vector field into cylindrical coordinates and then apply divergence formula in cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) page

Please note that $ \ \hat x, \hat y, \hat z$ unit vectors from cartesian coordinates are converted to cylindrical as,
$\hat x = \cos \varphi \ \hat \rho - \sin \varphi \ \hat \varphi, \hat y = \sin \varphi \ \hat \rho + \cos \varphi \ \hat \varphi, \hat z = \hat z$.

So taking example of the first one,
$\vec A = \frac{7}{2} x \hat i + 2y^2 \hat j + 7z \hat k$ can be written in cylindrical coordinates as,

$\vec A = \displaystyle \small \frac{7 \rho \cos \varphi}{2} (\cos \varphi \ \hat \rho - \sin \varphi \ \hat \varphi) + 2 \rho^2 \sin^2\varphi \ (\sin \varphi \ \hat \rho + \cos \varphi \ \hat \varphi) + 7z \ \hat z$

$ = \displaystyle \small \frac{7 \rho \cos^2 \varphi + 4 \rho^2 \sin^3\varphi}{2} \hat \rho + \frac{4 \rho^2 \sin^2 \varphi \cos \varphi - 7 \rho \sin\varphi \cos\varphi}{2} \hat \varphi + 7z \ \hat z$

Now in cylindrical coordinates, $\nabla \cdot \vec A = \displaystyle \small \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial (\rho A_{\rho})}{\partial \rho} + \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial A_{\varphi}}{\partial \varphi} + \frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial z}$

The first term evaluates to $(7 \cos^2\varphi + 6 \rho \sin^2\varphi)$, the second term evaluates to $(4 \rho \sin \varphi \cos^2\varphi - 2 \rho\sin^3\varphi - \frac{7}{2}\cos2\varphi)$ and the last term is simply $7$.

Adding them up and simplifying, you get

$\nabla \cdot \vec A = \displaystyle \small \frac{21}{2} + 4 \rho \sin \varphi$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Makes sense to me. I have two question 

1. If I don't change the vector to cylindrical coordinates, evaluate divergent of the vector I get  (21/2) + 4y and the replace y from the cylindrical coordinates I get the same result as If I had done the entire transformation...is that the wrong way to do it?

2. How would you interpret double rotational of A?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. You can of course do that if question did not specifically asked you to transform to cylindrical for operation.

Comment: Double rotational would mean $\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec A)$ or you can write it as $\nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec A) - \nabla^2 \vec A$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I forgot to ask you. The last exercise says rotational of AB, how do I interpret that? $\nabla \times (A\bullet B)$ or $\nabla \times (A \times B)$

Comment: There seems a typo. It should have been $A \times B$.